# Как правильно хранить картинки для товаров?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть товары для интернет-магазина, для каждого есть картинки, их может быть несколько. БД mysql, сайт написан на php. Сделал таблицу `product_has_images (product_id, image_link)`, чтобы добавлять туда картинки, но как выбрать главную картинку, которая будет видна везде? (Остальные будут видны только на странице товара) Правильно ли будет сделать столбец isMain и выставлять для главной картинки значение 1, для остальных 0?

Comment: Почему бы в товар не вписать главную картинку?

Answer (score 1):

Да, так и надо делать. + Поставить дефолтное значение поля в 0.

Answer (score 1):

"Главная" картинка - это моно-атрибут сущности Товар. Причём атрибут, связанный с сущностью соотношением N:1 - ведь одна и та же картинка может быть главной для нескольких товаров. Следовательно, для этого атрибута следует ввести в таблицу товара поле-ссылку на таблицу картинок.

Остальные картинки являются мульти-атрибутами сущности Товар, т.е. связаны с товарами соотношением N:N, следовательно, должны существовать таблица картинок и таблица соответствия товар-картинка.

Comment: Но это более сложно, если клиент через админку захочет поменять фото товара, нет?

Comment: @Alexxosipov *это более сложно, если клиент через админку захочет поменять фото товара, нет?* С чего бы? на форму тупо выводятся все картинки товара, а основная помечается чекбоксом. И, если надо, переставляешь чекбокс на другую картинку, если надо, добавляешь в список картинки или удаляешь их оттуда, при удалении основной или смещаешь чекбокс на случайную (скажем, первую), или оставляешь товар без основной картинки... вот убей - не вижу во всём этом сложностей.

Comment: Да, поразмыслил, ты прав, все на самом деле просто

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, как вариант, или повесить на загруженные файлы префиксы, 01,02,03 при заливе на сервер и тогда задать 01 основным в php, я еще реализовал несколько вариантов, когда клиенту предложил менять порядок фото, путем добавления в mysql дополнительной колонки которая является первоочередным ORDER'ом.

Comment: А если захочется поменять главную картинку, то придется перебивать все. Вариант с доп. полем более гибкий.

Comment: Если нужно сменить главную картинку я делаю запись в  БД, о том какая картинка в данный момент имеет приоритет.